# WebSphere Application Server can not start in command line

Tags: websphere

I installed WebSphere Application server 8.5 trial version, when I try run the startServer.bat in the commmand line, it shows it need a profile,no default profile exist and a profile name was not specified.But when I run the WASService.exe in the command line, it's fine.

Comment: What is the output for `manageprofiles.bat -listProfiles` ?

Answer (score 0):

You generally need to run startServer from the profile directory, i.e. **${WAS_INSTALL_ROOT}/profiles/${USER_INSTALL_ROOT}**, unless there is a default profile defined. USER_INSTALL_ROOT is the name of the profile.

A node might have several profiles installed so it needs to know where to look to find the server definition.

You can use the manageProfiles command to list profiles and also to check/set the default profile for the machine.

Have a look at the documentation of startServer and manageProfiles commands at the IBM Infocenter.

Comment: WAS 8.5 is installed but unable to start because of the mentioned issue. How can I import a profile to WAS without even starting it. I already have a *.car created which I can import. please suggest.